# How to get the Highlighted Content App to Work?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I started using the new UI in SharePoint Online, and I'm trying to create a modern page.  One of the new apps available is called Highlight Content, but I have been unable to get the app to return any content at all.

I've tried adding a modern page with this app to several different sites now.  All of the sites have one or more document libraries with content that has changed recently.  I tried changing the filters around on the app to try filtering All Documents, across the site collection, etc, but so far nothing is returned.  I've also tried kicking off a reindex of all the document libraries and the sites, but that also had no effect.  The Site Activity app works exactly as expected.

I'm wondering if I"m missing a setting or if this app simply doesn't work yet?  Any help in getting this figured out would be much appreciated.